# core text displayed text is drawn without spacing

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey, core-text

I'm trying to display text using coretext. Now it's on a delphi form, but I have code which seems to work fine getting the context for drawing shapes on (it just gets the FContext field from the form).

The text appears like this (it's upside down), it's suppose to be 'at'

[image: The text appears like this]

Now here's the code, just put it in a formpaint

```
 var
  cgcontext : CGContextRef;
  path : CGMutablePathRef;
  framesetter : CTFramesetterRef;
  frame : CTFrameRef;
  attrString: CFAttributedStringRef;

  function GetCGContextFromCanvas(ACanvas: TCanvas): CGContextRef;
  var
    Context: TRttiContext;
    Field: TRttiField;
  begin
    Field := Context.GetType(ACanvas.ClassType).GetField('FContext');
    Assert(Field <> nil);
    Result := PPointer(Field.GetValue(ACanvas).GetReferenceToRawData)^;
  end;
begin
  cgcontext := GetCGContextFromCanvas(Canvas);
  path := CGPathCreateMutable(); //1
  CGPathAddRect(path, nil, CGRectMake(0,0,600,200));
  attrString := CFAttributedStringCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR('at'), nil);
  framesetter := CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrString); //3
  frame := CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 2), path, nil);

  CTFrameDraw(frame, cgcontext); //4
end;
```

Any suggestions on why the spacing is wrong? Shouldn't it use the default spacing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

..it's because the textmatrix is set somewhere, but because it's not restored when you do CGContextSaveGState/CGContextRestoreGState the textmatrix is wrong. So just add a  `CGContextSetTextMatrix(cgcontext, CGAffineTransformIdentity);`